# Pushing objects in an array to a different array by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am trying to push an array of objects to another existing array of objects.

Example:

```
var invoices = [ 
{ 
  InvoiceId: 2,
  Contact: 'Jim',
  InvoiceNumber: '3',
  LineItems: [] 
},
{ 
  InvoiceId: 1002,
  Contact: 'Peter',
  InvoiceNumber: '4' },
  LineItems: [] 
}];


var invoiceLines = [ 
{ Id: 1003,
 InvoiceId: 2 },
 Amount: 1000,
{ Id: 1004,
 InvoiceId: 2,
 Amount: 1000,
{ Id: 1006,
 InvoiceId: 1002,
 Amount: 3000,}];
```

So I am trying to take each object in the **invoiceLines** array, and push it to **invoices.Lineitems** *if* **InvoiceId** matches. So it would look like this:

```
var result= [ 
{ 
 InvoiceId: 2,
 Contact: 'Jim',
 InvoiceNumber: '3',
 LineItems: [{ 
   Id: 1003,
   InvoiceId: 1002,
   Amount: 1000},{ 
   Id: 1004,
   InvoiceId: 1002,
   Amount: 1000}] 
},
{ 
 InvoiceId: 1002,
 Contact: 'Peter',
 InvoiceNumber: '4' },
 LineItems: [{
   Id: 1006,
   InvoiceId: 1002,
   Amount: 3000}] 
}];
```

I have tried the following:

```
var result = _({})
 .merge(
  _(flattenedinvoiceLines).groupBy("InvoiceId").value(),
  _(invoices).groupBy("Id").value())
 .values()
 .flatten()
 .value();
}
```

How ever this just pushes into the invoices array, not invoice.LineItems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can walk through `invoices` and then find all matches in `invoiceLines` by validating the `InvoiceId` is the same. below sample code

```js
var invoices = [ 
{ 
  InvoiceId: 2,
  Contact: 'Jim',
  InvoiceNumber: '3',
  LineItems: []
},
{ 
  InvoiceId: 1002,
  Contact: 'Peter',
  InvoiceNumber: '4',
  LineItems: [] 
}
];

var invoiceLines = [
{ Id: 1003,
 InvoiceId: 2,
 Amount: 1000 
},
{ Id: 1004,
 InvoiceId: 2,
 Amount: 1000,
 },
{ Id: 1006,
 InvoiceId: 1002,
 Amount: 3000
 }
 ];
 
  
 
const result = invoices.map(invoice => {
  invoice.LineItems = invoiceLines.filter((line) => line.InvoiceId === invoice.InvoiceId)
  return invoice;
})
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: Perfect - Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using [**Lodash**](https://lodash.com/), use:

- [**`_.map`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map) to iterate over the `invoices` array
- [**`_.filter`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#filter) to find each matching lines from `invoiceLines` according to `InvoiceId: item.InvoiceId`
- [**`_.extend`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#assignIn) to add each filtered and matched `invoiceLine`s to `LineItems`

#### ES5 Example:

```js
var invoices = [{
    InvoiceId: 2,
    Contact: 'Jim',
    InvoiceNumber: '3',
    LineItems: []
  },
  {
    InvoiceId: 1002,
    Contact: 'Peter',
    InvoiceNumber: '4',
    LineItems: []
  }
];

var invoiceLines = [{
    Id: 1003,
    InvoiceId: 2,
    Amount: 1000
  },
  {
    Id: 1004,
    InvoiceId: 2,
    Amount: 1000
  },
  {
    Id: 1006,
    InvoiceId: 1002,
    Amount: 3000
  }
];

var mergedInvoices = _.map(invoices, function(item) {
  _.extend(item.LineItems, _.filter(invoiceLines, { InvoiceId: item.InvoiceId }));    
  return item;
});

console.log(mergedInvoices);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

#### ES6 Example:

```js
const invoices = [{
    InvoiceId: 2,
    Contact: 'Jim',
    InvoiceNumber: '3',
    LineItems: []
  },
  {
    InvoiceId: 1002,
    Contact: 'Peter',
    InvoiceNumber: '4',
    LineItems: []
  }
];

const invoiceLines = [{
    Id: 1003,
    InvoiceId: 2,
    Amount: 1000
  },
  {
    Id: 1004,
    InvoiceId: 2,
    Amount: 1000
  },
  {
    Id: 1006,
    InvoiceId: 1002,
    Amount: 3000
  }
];

const mergedInvoices = _.map(invoices, item => {
  _.extend(item.LineItems, _.filter(invoiceLines, { InvoiceId: item.InvoiceId }));    
  return item;
});

console.log(mergedInvoices);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```